# Django Expiration Job does not pass test

Tags: python, django, unit-testing

I am quite new to testing in Django, so please excuse any obvious blunders. For some reason, my test that is checking if the token is deleted is failing and I don't understand why. Perhaps I am doing the database query wrong? Thanks in advance!

```
def delete_expired_auth_tokens():
    expiration_time = make_aware(datetime.now() - timedelta(hours=TOKEN_LIFETIME_HOURS))
    expired_tokens = DefaultTokenModel.objects.filter(created__lte=expiration_time)
    for token in expired_tokens:
        token.delete()

class AuthTokenDeleteTest(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        now = datetime.now()
        date_to_delete = now - timedelta(hours=(TOKEN_LIFETIME_HOURS+1))
        user_1, user_2 = User.objects.create(), User.objects.create(username='lol')
        DefaultTokenModel.objects.create(key='deletethistoken', created=date_to_delete, user_id=user_1.id)
        DefaultTokenModel.objects.create(key='dontdeletethistoken', created=now, user_id=user_2.id)
        delete_expired_auth_tokens()

    def test_does_not_delete(self):
        self.assertIsNotNone(DefaultTokenModel.objects.get(key='dontdeletethistoken'))

    def test_does_delete(self):
        self.assertIsNone(DefaultTokenModel.objects.get(key='deletethistoken'))
```